# Sum of absolute values of polynomials with python numpy

Tags: python, numpy, polynomials

Here's what I wrote: it's a classical exercise on interpolation, which I already finished and sent. I was wondering if there was another (longer) way...

`q` is a list of floats (the points of interpolation)

`i` is the index of the Lagrange polynomial

`x` is the point where is evaluated:

```
def l(q,i,x):
    poly=1.0
    for j,p in enumerate(q):
        if j==i:
            continue
        poly *=(x-p)/(q[i]-p)
    return poly
```

Then there is the function on which I'm working:

```
def Lambda(q,x):
    value=0.0
    for j in range(0,len(q)):
        value+=abs(l(q,j,x))
    return value
```

Now I can use some routines of python to find it's maxium value in the interval [0,1] and I did. 
In python there is a polynomial module, with which I can easily re-define l:

```
import numpy.polynomial.polynomial as P

def l_poly(q,i):
    poly = []
    for j,p in enumerate(q):
        if j==i:
            continue
        poly.append(p/(q[i]-p))
    return P.polyfromroots(poly)
```

I'd like to do the same with `Lambda` so that I can find its maximum using the built in function of the derivative (find its zeros and so on and so forth). The problem is that it is a sum of `abs(polynomials)`. Is there a way to do this? Or to mix the polynomial derivative and the derivative of `abs(...)`?

Comment: Do you need `abs(Poly1) + abs(Poly2) + abs(Poly3)...` or `abs(Poly1 + Poly2 + Poly3...)`?

Comment: I don't know if it is possible but as you see the function is abs(poly1)+abs(poly2) and so forth... But maybe the polynomials library  simply doesn't support it...

Answer (score 0):

NumPy does not support arbitrary symbolic expression. It works only with polynomials, representing a polynomial as an array of coefficients. The absolute value of a polynomial is not a polynomial, so it is not a concept that NumPy has. It's a symbolic expression that can be handled by symbolic manipulation libraries like SymPy.

> using the built in function of the derivative (find its zeros and so on and so forth).

There are several problems with this:

1. As said before, the `polyder` method of NumPy does not apply to this situation, since abs(polynomial) is not a polynomial.
2. The derivative of absolute function is undefined at 0.
3. The minimum or maximum of an expression involving absolute values may be attained where the derivative does not exist, so even if you could find the derivative, and somehow find its roots, you still would not solve the problem.
4. Looking for zeros of derivative is not a good way to minimize or maximize a function, outside of calculus exercises. Libraries like [`scipy.optimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html) implement many efficient numerical methods for this kind of problems.